# Test model coefficient (regression slope) against some value

Tags: r, regression, t-test

In R, when I have a (generalized) linear model (`lm`, `glm`, `gls`, `glmm`, ...), how can I test the coefficient (regression slope) against any other value than 0? In the summary of the model, t-test results of the coefficient are automatically reported, but only for comparison with 0. I want to compare it with another value.

I know I can use a trick with reparametrizing `y ~ x` as `y - T*x ~ x`, where `T` is the tested value, and run this reparametrized model, but I seek simpler solution, that would possibly work on the original model.

Comment: related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29981/should-confidence-intervals-for-linear-regression-coefficients-be-based-on-the-n

Answer (score 22):

Here's a broader solution that will work with any package, or even if you only have the regression output (such as from a paper).

Take the coefficient and its standard error.

Compute $t=\frac{\hat{\beta}-\beta_{H_0}}{\text{s.e.}(\hat{\beta})}$. The d.f. for the $t$ are the same as they would be for a test with $H_0: \beta=0$.

Comment: Thanks Glen, I know this from [this great answer]. But how will I get p-value from the t-value?

Comment: @Curious `pt()`

Comment: @Curious: As Affine saysm the R function `pt`  - or anything else that gives you the value of t cdfs.  Many packages have these, and there are widely available t-tables.

Comment: It would be nice if lm, lmer and the others accepted a test parameter different from zero directly.

Comment: @skan it's literally a single line of R code to get a p-value; it would be a simple matter to write a little function to take the output of summary.lm and produce a new table to your exact specifications.

Comment: Could you also reply my question in Glen_b answer, please?

Comment: What about lm(I(y - T*x) ~ x, ...) ?
That way you would be substracting something not independent. Wouldn't it be a problem with the assumptions for least squares or with collinearity? How is it different from lm(y ~ x  +offset(T*x))?

Answer (score 16):

You can use either a simple t-test as proposed by Glen_b, or a more general Wald test.

The Wald test allows to test multiple hypotheses on multiple parameters. It is formulated as: $R\beta=q$ where R selects (a combination of)  coefficients, and q indicates the value to be tested against, $\beta$ being the standard regresison coefficients.

In your example, where you have just one hypothesis on one parameter, R is a row vector, with a value of one for the parameter in question and zero elsewhere, and q is a scalar with the restriction to test.

In R, you can run a Wald test with the function *linearHypothesis()* from package *car*. Let us say you want to check if the second coefficient (indicated by argument **hypothesis.matrix**) is different than 0.1 (argument **rhs**):

```
reg <- lm(freeny)
coef(reg)

# wald test for lag.quarterly.revenue =0.1
>library(car)
>linearHypothesis(reg, hypothesis.matrix = c(0, 1, rep(0,3)), rhs=0.1)
#skip some result, look at last value on last row, of Pr(>F) 
  Res.Df       RSS Df  Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     35 0.0073811                            
2     34 0.0073750  1 6.0936e-06 0.0281 0.8679
```

For the t-test,  this function implements the t-test shown by Glen_b:

```
ttest <- function(reg, coefnum, val){
  co <- coef(summary(reg))
  tstat <- (co[coefnum,1]-val)/co[coefnum,2]
  2 * pt(abs(tstat), reg$df.residual, lower.tail = FALSE)
}

> ttest(reg, 2,0.1)
[1] 0.8678848
```

Let us make sure we got the right procedure by comparing the Wald, our t-test, and R default t-test, for the standard hypothesis that the second coefficient is zero:

```
> linearHypothesis(reg, hypothesis.matrix = c(0, 1, rep(0,3)), rhs=0)[["Pr(>F)"]][2]
[1] 0.3904361
> ttest(reg, 2,0)
[1] 0.3904361
## The 'right' answer from R:
> coef(summary(reg))[2,4]
[1] 0.3904361
```

You should get the same result with the three procedures.

Comment: looks good! Can you please explain the `hypothesis.matrix` parameter?

Comment: I am not sure if the Wald test does it. I meant to use the normal t-test which is standardly reported along with the parameters, but not with 0 but with some other value.

Comment: @Curious Hope it is clearer now?

Answer (score 3):

In the end, farly the easiest solution was to do the reparametrization:

```
gls(I(y - T*x) ~ x, ...)
```

Comment: Will that produce the same results?

Comment: But you are substracting something not independent. Wouldn't it be a problem with the assumptions for least squares or with collinearity?  How is it different from lm(y ~ x + +offset(T*x))?

Comment: @skan the regression is conditional on x, there's no dependence there; it should be the same as using offset.