# How to compare my slope to 1 rather than 0 using regression analysis and t distribution?

Tags: regression, t-test, t-distribution

I would like to know if i can reject, using a linear regression and a t-distribution, the following Null hypothesis:

b=1

where b is the slope of my linear regression. My hypothesis is that b>1.

I am using R, and i know how to test whether my slope is significantly different than 0 but not if it is significantly different than 1!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Duplicate of this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/111559/5509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pt, which returns a p-value from a t distribution.

You will need to supply the correct quantile and degrees of freedom.  For instance, for a two sided test where $\sigma_{\beta1}$ is the estimate of the standard error of the regression line, at a significance level of .05%:

```
pvalue <- pt(q = (b1 - 1)/sigma_beta1, df = n - 2, lower.tail = FALSE) * 2
```

Comment: Thank you! Quick question, why did you multiply the whole thing by 2?

Comment: pt returns a p-value for one tail.  Since I am looking for a confidence interval ( two tailed ), I multiplied by 2 so that I could compare the returned p-value with the significance level $\alpha$, so that I could interpret the p-value properly.